# Saving Images in SQL using C#

Tags: c#

I have a dialog box in a C# Winforms application. I want to save images. But each time I click on the save button, I get an error

> A generic error occurred in gdi+

This is my code for saving the image:

```
var SavedFileName = string.Format(@"{0}.png", Guid.NewGuid());

var path = Application.StartupPath + "/passport/" + SavedFileName.ToString();

if(passportsize.Image == null)
{
    SavedFileName = "";
}
else
{
    passportsize.Image.Save(path,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Comment: Does the directory exist?

Comment: Not at the moment

Comment: That's probably the problem.

Comment: just created it.Same error

Comment: Unrelated: notice that the `.ToString` on `SavedFileName` is redundant since it is already a string. And I would recommend using `Path.Combine` to construct the file path. Specifically `var path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "passport", SavedFileName);`. Are you using Linux or Windows?

Comment: am using Windows

Comment: Then definitely use Path Combine (as shown in my last comment) since the directory separator character is backslash on Windows, not forward slash.

Comment: A slash in file path is not going to cause a GDI+ error. Your `passportsize.Image` is probably not an image format that GDI+ understands.

Comment: Also, `Application.StartupPath` is a very bad place to try to save a file; it's probably not writable by non-admins, and will get deleted if you uninstall or repair your application. Save user data in [`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Environment_GetFolderPath_System_Environment_SpecialFolder_).

Answer (score 1):

Try using a back slash instead of a forward slash.
"`\\passport`\\" instead of "/passport/"

Comment: That won't compile.

Comment: You will need to escape the backslashes by doubling them

Comment: @Hans Indeed, I was prompting Terry to do improve the answer.

Comment: Thanks @John. Getting both of them to show up was a little tricky.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the full message, so I can't be sure, but it's likely that the source stream that created the image has been disposed of but the image is still tied to it.

When you create the image, you should clone it. For example:

```
private Image ImageFromBytes(byte[] imageBytes)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
    {
        using (var image = Image.FromStream(ms))
        {
            return (Image)image.Clone();
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you come to save it later, you shouldn't encounter any issues.